# Cleanse build failed on xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, cleanse

I try to build my legacy code on xcode 9, swift version 3.2 with the Cleanse dependency injector, but the `static func configure<B: Binder>(binder: Binder)` function got the following error:

> Reference to generic type 'Binder' requires arguments in <...>

I tried all the branches and commits. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
struct Singleton : Scope {
}

static func configure(binder: Binder<Singleton>) {
     // Will fill out contents later
}
```

You can check an example here:
https://github.com/square/Cleanse/blob/master/CleansePlayground.playground/Pages/CoffeeMakerExample.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to have changed

> ```
> func configure<B : Binder>(binder binder: B) {
>        // Will fill out contents later
>    }
> ```
>
> https://github.com/square/Cleanse

Comment: The Binder type come from the Cleanse:
https://github.com/square/Cleanse/blob/master/Cleanse/BindToable.swift

Comment: In the doc of Cleanse, I found this function referred to as "func configure<B: Binder>(binder binder: B)" Is it what you are trying to implement ?

Comment: Yes it is. And it worked perfectly with earlier xcodes

Comment: It's a tiny difference, but it may change it all

Comment: thank you, it is changed more I think, in this file you can check it. it is working with this syntax:
[https://github.com/square/Cleanse/blob/master/CleansePlayground.playground/Pages/CoffeeMakerExample.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift]
the documentation may outdated i'll send a PR to them.
If you edit your answer i will mark it as the correct answer, thank you your help